# KVM slow guest i/o

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

**Host:**

Debian 6.0 (squeeze) with qemu-kvm and libvirt from squeeze-backports

`ii  qemu-kvm                            1.0+dfsg-8~bpo60+1`

`ii  libvirt-bin                         0.9.8-2~bpo60+2`

Has 3TB sata drives with software raid and lvm. It has a sequential write speed of **~140MB/s** measured with `dd bs=1M count=512 if=/dev/zero of=test conv=fdatasync`

Elevator set to cfq

**Guest**

Debian 6.0 (squeeze)

Uses LVM as storage. Drivers are virtio and cache='none'

Sequential write speed is considerably slower with only **25-50MB/s**

Elevator set to noop

I'm kind of running out of ideas for further tweaks but I'm sure that I/O speed should be much faster because many people are reporting almost native performance with lvm.

Comment: Are you using the virtio block driver?

Comment: Ok, something weird happened. I ran those tests again today when I woke up and the difference is noticeable. All squeeze guest are now up to native performance. But one older lenny guest is still having problems - max. 50MB/s. What could be happening? Is it the older kernel? 2.6.26-2-amd64 ...

Comment: I noticed one more thing when looking at 'lspci' output on squeeze and lenny boxes. Squeeze has: SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio block device | Lenny has: SCSI storage controller: Qumranet, Inc. Device 1001 | ... why is that? Both have virtio enabled..

Comment: Ah, I found out that qumranet actually is the virtio controler I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this has been finally solved. The problem was in partition misalignment. It looks like Debian's default installer (especially lenny?) can't do the alignment properly, because when I checked the partitions it made with parted, it reported misalignment on all of them.

I solved this by manually partitioning LVM with parted prior to installation and now all guests are enjoying full performance.

Comment: Could you possibly add some more information on what you did here?  Misalignment on host or guest?  What needed to be done to resolve it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8592/how-do-i-align-my-partition-table-properly is useful enough; looks like this isn't my problem, although I have much worse performance problems than you did (125MB/s on the host, <1MB/s on the guest).

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your host's I/O elevator to `deadline`. Keep the guest at `noop`.

Comment: It's maybe just a tiny bit better but still nowhere near expectations.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, try to test the speeds with `direct` option, to eliminate the possibility of looking at the wrong results. 
Then, what you describe is something I've seen quite often on Debian and Ubuntu, any chance you can bring up a Fedora or RHEL host and guests to recheck?

Comment: Fedora is unfortunately out of the question because I can't reinstall anymore. Machine is already serving a few sites that need to be online.

Comment: your recent update kinda proved my point :)

Comment: What point? That debian is unpredictable? :)

Comment: that performance can depend on the distro. Problem is - most kvm devs work on fedora, and the rest of the distros take code from it. How well they adapt the code is something that's completely out of anyone's control :)

Answer (score 0):

For the best possible speed you should preallocate the image and use the raw format !

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM